# How do I mix underscore functions to use a custom comparison algorithm for _.contains()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Ideally, I want to pass a custom comparison function to `_.contains()` as a third argument, but it only accepts a collection and a value.

**Code**

I want to do this:

```
_.contains(['apples', 'oranges'], 'applesss', function (element, value) {
  return new RegExp(element).test(value);
});
```

... but I can't, so what's the next best thing?

Comment: You can simply loop in native JavaScript, create your own `contains`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [_.some](http://underscorejs.org/#some), which returns `true` if the test passes for at least one element in the array:

```
_.some(['apples', 'oranges'], function (element) {
  return new RegExp(element).test('applesss');
});
```

You can easily wrap it in your own function:

```
function test_regexes(arr, value) {
  return _.some(arr, function (element) {
    return new RegExp(element).test(value);
  });
}

test_regexes(['apples', 'oranges'], 'applesss');
```